# How do I highlight the correct answer when an incorrect answer is chosen in my Angular 8 reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need some help with highlighting the correct answer with green and checkmark at the same time when an incorrect answer is chosen (which is highlighted red). Please see my form's code below:

```
<form #quizForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ol class="form-group">
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="answer" name="answer" (change)="radioChange($event.value)"
      (click)="question.selectedOption = option">
       <div class="radio-options" *ngFor="let option of question.options">
         <mat-radio-button class="option" [value]="option.optionValue" disableRipple="true"
          [checked]="question.selectedOption == option"
          [ngClass]="{'is-correct': isCorrect(option.optionValue),
                      'is-incorrect': isIncorrect(option.optionValue)}">
          <li>{{ option.optionText }}</li>

          <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="isCorrect(option.optionValue)">done</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="isIncorrect(option.optionValue)">clear</mat-icon>
        </mat-radio-button>


private buildForm() {
  this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    answer: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}

radioChange(answer: number) {
  this.selectedOption = answer;
  // this.answer.emit(answer);
  this.displayExplanation();
}

isCorrect(option: number): boolean {
  return option === this.question.answer && this.selectedOption === option;
}

isIncorrect(option: number): boolean {
  return option !== this.question.answer && this.selectedOption === option;
}
```

EDIT: trying to do something like this, not sure how to link it to my template, because I'm already using ngClass on the DOM element :) ...

```
checkAnswer() {
  let radioElem = document.getElementById('mat-radio-btn');

  if (this.question.selectedOption === this.question.answer) {
    radioElem.classList.add('is-correct');
  } else {
    radioElem.classList.add('is-incorrect');
    if (radioElem.innerHTML === this.question.answer) {
      radioElem.classList.add('is-correct');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: don't know how to highlight the correct answer at the same time as incorrect

Comment: Can you post your method as well? also Is it working fine for correct answers?

Comment: Yes it works fine for correct answers. Just would like it to highlight the correct answer when the wrong answer is chosen. I'm adding my methods to the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is change your methods to not do anything until an option is selected:

```
isCorrect(option: number): boolean {
  // mark the correct answer regardless of which option is selected once answered
  return !!this.selectedOption && option === this.question.answer;
}

isIncorrect(option: number): boolean {
  // mark incorrect answer if selected
  return option !== this.question.answer && this.selectedOption === option;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not sure about, how you code in your methods. But I think ideally your code looks like -

```
        <mat-radio-button class="option" [value]="option.optionValue" disableRipple="true"
          [checked]="question.selectedOption == option"
          [ngClass]="{'is-correct': isCorrect(option.optionValue),
                      'is-incorrect': !isCorrect(option.optionValue)}">
          <li>{{ option.optionText }}</li>

          <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="isCorrect(option.optionValue)">done</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="!isCorrect(option.optionValue)">clear</mat-icon>
        </mat-radio-button>
```

and Your method should looks like -

```
isCorrect(option: number): boolean {
  this.selectedOption = option;
  return option === this.question.answer
}
```

PS: No need to add click handler, if you are already added `change` event. Just set the value in change handler, Or you can use model binding using `ngModel` instead if you want.

Comment: Modified my code but all the wrong answers are highlighting at the same time.

Comment: No I want the selected wrong answer to be highlighted red and the correct answer to be highlighted green

Comment: can you create simple stackblitz example for the same?

Comment: In your example, Your code is working as per your expectations. please check it is highlighting only single answer at a time.

Comment: I would like it to highlight the correct answer when an incorrect answer is given. It is not currently doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201611/discussion-between-multiv123-and-pardeep-jain).

Comment: I found an example of a quiz where they have highlighted the incorrect and correct answer at the same time if you select an incorrect answer: https://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/quizshow.php?title=3dq-how-well-do-you-know-dependency-injection&q=1

Comment: I'm having trouble with automatically increasing the score when the correct option is clicked. I've tried calling the function in various places but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ok got the automatic scoring working, just would like the highlighting to work the way I need it to

Comment: this kind of function call with an assignment in template is extremely bad practice and seems very unpredictable in it's behavior

Comment: True that @bryan60 But question was not much clear so I posted it as alternate.